# Unable to use multiple modal's on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to have multiple modal's on the same page.  Right now I just have two.  One that loads content dynamically, and another the shows a loading gif when a file is being deleted.  The loading gif modal works fine as it opens and closes on its own as it should.  But the main modal that loads its content dynamically looses the ability to close.  When I hover over the close button or link it does not change to the pointer, it is like it does not recognize the button is there.

If I remove the loading gif modal, the dynamic modal works fine.  I have tried to do different modals, but they all have the same problem.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="text-center">Link Details</h1>
</div>
<div id="linkDetailsWrapper">
<!-- Note - This content is loaded dynamically -->
    <div class="col-lg-6 uploadFiles" id="uploadFiles-right">
        <h3 class="text-center">Uploaded By Customer</h3>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs">Date Added</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/download/130">someFile.ext</a></td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs">2016-02-26 17:01:16</td>
                        <td><a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-noteid="20" data-original-title="Click to view Note"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></span></a></td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs"><a title="Delete File" class="delete-file-link" data-fileid="130" data-tooltip="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--  End of dynamic content  -->   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4>File Notes:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>The Body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">      
    <img src="/source/img/loader.gif" alt="loading..." class="loadingModal" />
</div>
</div>

<script src="/source/js/uploadLinks.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#linkDetailsWrapper').load('/_links/details/45');
</script>
```

Content of uploadLinks.js:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-tooltip="tooltip"]', 
    trigger: 'hover'
});

$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e)
{
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var noteID = link.data('noteid');

    $(this).find('.modal-body').load('/_links/loadNote/'+noteID);
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete-file-link', function(e)
{
    var el = $(this);
    if(confirm('Are You Sure?\nThis Cannot Be Undone.'))
    {
        $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
        $.get('/_links/deleteNote/'+$(this).data('fileid'), function(data)
        {
            if(data == 'success')
            {
                el.closest('tr').remove();
                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('There was a problem deleting the file.\nAn error log has been generated.');
                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
            }     
        });
    }
});
```

Edit:  I found the solution.  I was using some CSS I found in another forum to center the modal on the page vertically.  This was causing my problem.  I removed the CSS and I am good to go now.

CSS Removed:

```
body.modal-open .modal {
    display: flex !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but I would put your img you have in your #loadingModal, inside at least a .modal-content - .modal-body, like you did for you #modal.

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't make a difference.  I am not using the modal-body and modal-content classes because they put the gif in the white modal content box.  Without it only the image shows and it looks nicer.